# LateX, BibTex, and citations not found by ArXiV

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, arxiv

I have recently submitted a paper on ArXiv, along with the corresponding .bbl file; while the compilation and end results are fine, it appears that the [SAO/NASA ADS](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/) service cannot parse the references to point to the ones that also appear on ArXiv.

To give an example, here is one excerpt of the bbl file:

```
\bibitem[ADK15]{ADK:15}
Jayadev Acharya, Constantinos Daskalakis, and Gautam Kamath.
\newblock Optimal testing for properties of distributions.
\newblock {\em CoRR}, abs/1507.05952, July 2015.
```

which point to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05952). However, the SAO/NASA ADS website [does not seem to have found this reference](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015arXiv150703558C), as it does not include a "References in the Article" link (which would list the corresponding cited arXiv papers, as e.g. is the case [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv:1506.00671)).

Is there a simple reason for this, something I did wrong in my bibtex/bbl file?* Or is it just completely arbitrary?

*The part of my bib file corresponding to the above snippet is:

```
@article{ADK:15,
  title = {Optimal Testing for Properties of Distributions},
  author = {Acharya, Jayadev and Daskalakis, Constantinos and Kamath, Gautam},
  journal   = {CoRR},
  eprint = {1507.05952},
  volume = {abs/1507.05952},
  primaryClass = "cs.DS",
  year = 2015,
  month = jul,
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015arXiv150705952A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Comment: You may have quicker results if you simply [contact ADS](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/user_feedback.html) directly and explain the situation. With no idea how their system works (is the code open?) any suggestions would be limited to blind guesses.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll try that. I wanted to make sure it was not some known issue with my way to format citations or use a bibliography...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Jared Kulik's comment above, I contacted [ADS](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/user_feedback.html) directly to enter the missing (arXiV) citations they couldn't find. After a few days, they added them, so that they now appear on their system.

Oddly enough, immediately after (and therefore more than 3 weeks after the posting of the paper online),  Google Scholar updated its records of the *other* papers cited in the bibliography (that is, not only these 3) to include the citations we have. Whether it is just a coincidence (and Google Scholar is only darned slow), or this adding 3 citations in the ADS system triggered something else for Google Scholar, leading to its parsing the other entries of the bibliography, I have no clue. But everything is well now.